# Log4net ConnectionString Doesn't work with SQL Azure

Tags: connection-string, log4net, azure-sql-database, log4net-configuration

I tried everything. With a Local File is working and I had to install a instance of SQL Server in my local machine and is also working but when I change my connection string to the SQL Azure doesn't work. I'm testing the same user and password in the Server Explorer inside of my Visual Studio where my application is and works. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 5):

I  spent the better part of the day trying to figure it out. The problem is that SQL Azure requires clustered indexes on your tables. The example SQL code provided by log4net (http://logging.apache.org/) and 99% of the tutorials on the internet, are to create the Log table does not have a clustered index, which is a requirement for SQL Azure. Adding any data at all to the table will fail unless it has a clustered index.

Try doing a manual insert statement using SQL Server Management Studio while connected to SQL Azure and it will tell you straight away if this is the problem. If so, run the following SQL to add a clustered index on the table (assuming you used the SQL direct from log4net) and then try again.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_Log ON [Log]
 ([Id])
GO
```